# Calculating discriminant of number ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha $ be a real root of $f(x) = x^3 - x +4$ (whose discriminant is $-428$). Consider $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $ R= \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

$(a)$ What is the integral basis of $K$?

$(b)$ What is the discriminant $\Delta_K$?

For part$(a)$, I showed that $R$ is not the ring of integers for  $K$ by noting that $ \beta = \frac{4}{\alpha}$ is a solution of $x^3 - x^2 +16 =0$. But, I'm not sure how I can show that $ \{1, \alpha,\beta \}$ is an integral basis of $K$. One way to do it would be by computing the discriminant but I don't know how to do that here as I don't have the explicit monomorphisms. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need “monomorphisms”. The discriminant of a basis can be  calculated intrinsically (no need for any embedding) as the determinant of a trace-pairing matrix. What are all the formulas you know for the discriminant of a basis in a field extension?

For example, if $K = \mathbf Q(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is a root of $x^3-x^2-2x-8$ then $\theta$ and $4/\theta$ are both algebraic integers in $K$ and the discriminant of $\{1,\theta,4/\theta\}$ is computed using a trace-pairing matrix in the proof of Theorem 1.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/nopowerbasis.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Dividing $f(\alpha)=0$ by $\alpha$ we see that $\beta=4/\alpha=1-\alpha^2$ is contained in ${\bf Z}[\alpha]$. However, $(\alpha^2+\alpha)/2$ is an algebraic integer not in ${\bf Z}[\alpha]$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. But, how did you find that element $\frac{\alpha^2 + \alpha }{2}$?

Comment: Often in practice $(\alpha^2+\alpha)/2$ works as an algebraic integer in cubic rings when $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ is too small.  For a systematic way to find a new algebraic integer outside $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ when it is too small, use “Dedekind’s index theorem”. See Theorems 1.4 and 4.1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekind-index-thm.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the degree of the extension $K|\mathbb{Q}$ is 3 because $f$ is irreducible. So in that case $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, that has $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2\}$ as a basis

Comment: But, I showed that $4/\alpha$ is an algebraic integer over $K$. How can $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ be an integral basis?

Comment: Sorry that's a power basis.  I misunderstood the question